# Setup Subdomain On Amazon Ec2

Tags: nginx, configuration, subdomain

On `ec2` I have the parent domain e.g. `somedomain.com` . I want to setup a subdomain on EC2 which is currently hosting `somedomain.com` - a subdomain like `account.somedomain.com`

`somedomain.com` is running nginx, with a sites-enabled config of:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name     *.somedomain.com;
        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/somedomain/somedomain/homelaunch/;

        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/somedomain/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/somedomain/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;

        location /static {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/somedomain/somedomain/homelaunch/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_read_timeout 10;
            proxy_connect_timeout 10;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

the `somedomain.com` is perfectly accessible using EC2, I would like to know how to include a `subdomain` like `account.somedomain.com` to the picture and serve different content.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an extra "server" block with the exact domain name you wish to serve.

As pointed out in the [server_name documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), the exact name takes precedence over wildcard names.

That effectively means that if you add something like this above or below the existing block, you should get the desired result.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  account.somedomain.org;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do I need to then reinstall everything again on this account.somedomain.org ? e.g. django, etc?

Comment: Additionally, does this require me to restart nginx to take effect?

Comment: Regarding nginx, if you don't change the listen port then no, you can just reload the configuration. `service nginx reload` will do in most Linux systems.
Regarding python and Django, I guess that it will be running behind a different gunicorn/uwsgi process, so you just have to direct the `proxy_pass` statement to the correct django instance.

Comment: @user700070 Django will operate with the proxy_pass directive, fyi.